# Android EditText.setHint not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, fragment

I have a fragment for the sliding menu I implemented and I encountered a problem with the EditText I am using in it. Unfortunately, whenever I type something into the EditText in my sliding menu, the hint is still shown. Therefore I tried to find a workaround, so I basically set the hint to nothing if nothing is in the EditText, but that does not work at all. The other code, that enables or disables a button based on the text, does work though. It's a mystery to me.

What it's doing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DEPN.png

My workaround:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        final Button addBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAddPlaylist);
        final EditText txtPlaylistName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtPlaylist);

        txtPlaylistName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                boolean hasContent = !String.valueOf(s).trim().isEmpty();

                addBtn.setEnabled(hasContent);
                txtPlaylistName.setHint((hasContent) ? "Create new Playlist..." : "");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's definitely more efficient than what I was doing, but it does not really change the outcome. The button disables and enables without any problems, there's just something very wrong with the EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call `setHint` with the string if your EditText is empty, not if it contains text. In your snippet, you have:

```
txtPlaylistName.setHint((hasContent) ? "Create new Playlist..." : "");
```

which set a hint even tough you still have some content,

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       boolean hasContent = (count != 0);
       addBtn.setEnabled(hasContent);
       txtPlaylistName.setHint((hasContent) ? null : "Create new Playlist...");
 }
```

Comment: Of course, it has to be vice versa. Totally messed that up. However, it still was not working, but I found the issue. I set the hint in the xml layout and for some reason it set another hint behind the existent hint. I got rid of that hint and did everything programmatically and that fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add hint to the layout container and it'll show as expected.It's the way of adding hint for the dynamically created EditText. 
Hope someone will get benefir from it.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = holder.itemViewfindViewById(R.id.value_text);
textInputLayout.setHint(your_value.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText etUsername;
etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
etUsername.setHint("Your Hint");

If you are using Editext within TextInputLayout then you need to change property of TextInputLayout not Edittext:

TextInputLayout layoutUser;
layoutUser = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputLayoutUname);
layoutUser.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hintFaculty));
```

Comment: May be you give the correct answer. However add some description how your code will work or fix the issue.

Comment: If you are using Editext within TextInputLayout then you need to change property of TextInputLayout not Edited:
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/White_TextInputLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ap_et_child_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>